# roslisp without ROS?

Tags: ros, roslisp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it possible to have only roslisp package without the ROS distribution on one machine, and communicate wit roscore running on different machine?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/36584/roslisp-without-ros?/) by [liborw](https://answers.ros.org/users/2302/liborw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 801 on 2012-06-15

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The only ROS specific thing in roslisp that I see at the moment is loading of asdf files inside ROS packages. For finding the path to a ROS package, it calls `rospack`. The corresponding code can be found in `load-manifest.lisp`. I assume if you comment out the following lines (line 276) in `load-manifest.lisp`, you should get it independent from all other ROS dependencies.

```
(setq asdf:*system-definition-search-functions* 
      (append asdf:*system-definition-search-functions*
              '(asdf-ros-search)))
```

roslisp will still search your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH for asd files but this shouldn't interfere with your normal asdf configuration. When you want to communicate over topics, make sure that you copy the message asd files that can be found in msg_gen/lisp of each package that defines messages.

**Update**: after thinking about it for a while, I don't think any ROS infrastructure is required for using roslisp. You even don't need to load load-manifest so if you remove the dependency on it in roslisp.asd, everything should still work fine. I have to double-check that though. I'm thinking about factoring out load-manifest into a separate package now since it is only used for loading asd files in ros packages.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-06-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You obviously need some very basic ROS things that roslisp depends on,
but not "the ROS distribution" if with that you mean something like ros-...-desktop-full.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-06-15

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1